# Implement Zoom API in a web application in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, zoom-sdk

I am developing a web application on the Vue Framework. But I ran into a problem and I don't know how to implement a Zoom API and any video calling company since my web application is dedicated to allowing different people with similar tastes to come in and talk to each other.

I would appreciate if you can explain to me how it could be done or what would be the process to carry out in order to implement it

Answer (score 0):

The Zoom API allows developers to access information from Zoom. You can use this API to build private services or public applications on the zoom app marketplace. To learn how to get your credentials and create private/public applications. All endpoints are available via **HTTPS** and are located at [api.zoom.us/v2/.](https://api.zoom.us/v2/.)

For **instance** you can list all users on an account via **https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).